# Xcode 8 releasing App Crash?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I get an error while uploading a build to the App store:

> "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at '$path' can't contain 16-bit or P3 assets if the app is targeting iOS releases earlier than iOS 9.3"

I used to upload it to Beta testing before just fine, My deployment target is 8.3.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is exactly solution for your issue

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39453818/1271424

You need to find all P3 assets and then convert them into sRGB color space (using any image editor). Here is the original answer:

> With Xcode 8 GM, this error will occur if you include 16-bit or P3
>   assets in an app submission targeting iOS releases earlier then iOS
>   9.3. If your app requires wide color functionality you must change your Deployment Target to iOS 9.3 or later. If your app does not
>   require wide color functionality and you wish to deploy it to older
>   iOS versions then you should replace all 16-bit or P3 assets with
>   8-bit sRGB assets.   You can find 16-bit or P3 assets by running
>   “assetutil” on the asset catalog named in the error message from
>   iTunes Connect. The following steps outline the process:
>
> 1. Create an Inspectable .ipa file.  In the Xcode Organizer (Xcode->Window->Organizer), select an archive to inspect, click
>      “Export...", and choose "Export for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment".
>      This will create a local copy of the .ipa file for your app.
> 2. Locate that .ipa file and change its the extension to .zip.
> 3. Expand the .zip file. This will produce a Payload folder containing your .app bundle.
> 4. Open a terminal and change the working directory to the top level of your .app bundle cd path/to/Payload/your.app
> 5. Use the find tool to locate Assets.car files in your .app bundle as shown below: find . -name 'Assets.car'
> 6. Use the assetutil tool to find any 16-bit or P3 assets, in each Assets.car your application has as shown below. : sudo xcrun --sdk
>      iphoneos assetutil --info /path/to/a/Assets.car > /tmp/Assets.json
> 7. Examine the resulting /tmp/Assets.json and look for any contents containing “DisplayGamut": “P3” and its associated “Name".  This will
>      be the name of your imageset containing one or more 16-bit or P3
>      assets.
> 8. Replace those assets with 8-bit / sRGB assets, then rebuild your app.
>
> Update:  If your Deployment Target is set to either 8.3 or 8.4 and you have an 
>   asset catalog then you will receive this same error message, even if you do not 
>   actually have 16-bit or P3 assets.  In this case you will either need to lower 
>   your Deployment Target to 8.2, or move it up to 9.x.