# Swift 3 GCD - compatibility for iOS 8.x 9.x

Tags: swift, swift3

our application was working well under Swift 2.3 in iOS 8, 9.

Now after migration to Swift 3, we are receiving random crashes.

One suspicion we have are classes around GCD.

Swift 3 migration forced us to stop using dispatch_async and similar calls in favour of DispatchQueue etc.

Question: 
DispatchQueue and all classes from GCD show SDK support 10+
https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchqueue

Is this a correct information? If so, does this mean Swift 3 GCD is not backward compatible?

thanks.

Note: the App migrated to Swift3 crashes at iOS 9.1 and lower, iOS 9.3 seems to be fine. Crashes are quite random, looking for the source.

Answer (score 0):

That's the sdk version that you're compiling so it's related to xcode not your iOS version.

Comment: thanks, my confusion. Seems like this is a duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404285/xcode-8-build-crash-on-ios-9-2-and-below