# ITMS-90682: "Invalid Bundle.

Tags: ios, xcode

Today I update my Xcode vision to 8.0. When I submit a app.ipa file to Apple store,i get an error feedback that ITMS-90682: "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at '$path' can't contain 16-bit or P3 assets if the app is targeting iOS releases earlier than iOS 9.3."].

I search the answer on the Internet and get a similar answer,but it not fit.

Because their question is not completely the same as mine.Their question contain 'Payload/****.app/Assets.car' ,but mine contain '$path'.

Their method is as follows:

First step : modify the file' name of app.ipa to app.zip

Second step : decompressing app.zip

Third step : undo command line and $ cd app.app file

Forth step: $  find . -name 'Assets.car'

Fifth step :  $ sudo xcrun --sdk iphoneos assetutil --info  /path/to/a/Assets.car > /tmp/Assets.json

Sixth step :  open /tmp/Assets.json

Seventh step : search "P3" and "16-bit" in file named "Assets.json"

Eighth step : record the "Name"

Ninth step : open Xcode and find out the image that names have been record in eighth step. change the image form to  8  and  sRGB

These are not use for mine ,because the different is "$path".i can't get the name of imaged which form is P3 or 16-bit in my project because i can't get a right method to get a property Assets.json file on fifth step.

Comment: Have a look at the Update in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39453818/1181553

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 8 build crash on iOS 9.2 and below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404285/xcode-8-build-crash-on-ios-9-2-and-below)

Comment: my question is not ''Payload/XXXXX/Assets.car'' but "$path".@miniBill

Answer (score 13):

Change you 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' to '8.2' if you used '8.3'.

Comment: That did it for me.

Answer (score 7):

**Short Answer**

We'll need to lower our Deployment Target to 8.2 to pass iTunes Connect

**Full Answer**

@dove lark this is from Apple Developer Forums, please check update paragraph :

> With Xcode 8 GM, this error will occur if you include 16-bit or P3
> assets in an app submission targeting iOS releases earlier then iOS
> 9.3. If your app requires wide color functionality you must change your Deployment Target to iOS 9.3 or later. If your app does not
> require wide color functionality and you wish to deploy it to older
> iOS versions then you should replace all 16-bit or P3 assets with
> 8-bit sRGB assets.   You can find 16-bit or P3 assets by running
> “assetutil” on the asset catalog named in the error message from
> iTunes Connect. The following steps outline the process:
>
> 1. Create an Inspectable .ipa file.  In the Xcode Organizer (Xcode->Window->Organizer), select an archive to inspect, click
>    “Export...", and choose "Export for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment".
>    This will create a local copy of the .ipa file for your app.
> 2. Locate that .ipa file and change its the extension to .zip.
> 3. Expand the .zip file. This will produce a Payload folder containing your .app bundle.
> 4. Open a terminal and change the working directory to the top level of your .app bundle cd path/to/Payload/your.app
> 5. Use the find tool to locate Assets.car files in your .app bundle as shown below: find . -name 'Assets.car'
> 6. Use the assetutil tool to find any 16-bit or P3 assets, in each Assets.car your application has as shown below. : sudo xcrun --sdk
>    iphoneos assetutil --info /path/to/a/Assets.car > /tmp/Assets.json
> 7. Examine the resulting /tmp/Assets.json and look for any contents containing “DisplayGamut": “P3” and its associated “Name".  This will
>    be the name of your imageset containing one or more 16-bit or P3
>    assets.
> 8. Replace those assets with 8-bit / sRGB assets, then rebuild your app.   **Update**:  If your Deployment Target is set to either 8.3 or 8.4
>    and you have an asset catalog then you will receive this same error
>    message, even if you do not actually have 16-bit or P3 assets.  In
>    this case you will either need to lower your Deployment Target to 8.2,
>    or move it up to 9.x.
>
> **Update**:  If your Deployment Target is set to either 8.3 or **8.4** and you
> have an asset catalog then you will receive this same error message,
> **even if you do not actually have 16-bit or P3 assets**.  In this case
> you will either need to lower your Deployment Target to 8.2, or move
> it up to 9.x.

[Apple Developer forums link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60919?tstart=0)

means we'll need to lower our Deployment Target to 8.2 to pass iTunes Connect.

Ridiculously fixed my problem, hope this will help someone else...