# Crashlytics - I'm getting lots of crash report from ios 9.1-9.2 after releasing new version

Tags: crashlytics

I released a new version of my application a couple of hours ago.

I suddenly get a lot of crash (about 50 - until now) reports that I didn't have till now.

The common of all crashes is:
iOS version 9.1-9.2
Crash types are: EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

What changed from the previous version:
iOS minimum target changed from 7 to 8
xCode changed from 7 to 8
fabric updated to the version 2.6.4 (1271)

I didn't find any explanation for that

I'd appreciate your help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404285/xcode-8-build-crash-on-ios-9-2-and-below

Answer (score 1):

I have crash similar in only iOS 9.2.x - 9.1.x, 9.0.x
No crash in 9.3.x, 10.x.x, 11.x.x
Is it error iOS system?
I use Swift 3.x